# Computing the derivative of a matrix-valued function

Tags: derivatives, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

Suppose $\mathbf{A} :\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that $\mathbf{A}(\theta)$ is a symmetric matrix. Let $\mathbf{A}(\theta)$ have the eigen-decomposition $\mathbf{A}(\theta) = \mathbf{U}(\theta)~\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1(\theta),\ldots,\lambda_m(\theta))~\mathbf{U}(\theta)^\top$. If I have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and I *define*
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{A}(\theta)) = \mathbf{U}(\theta) ~\mathrm{diag}(f(\lambda_1(\theta)),\ldots,f(\lambda_m(\theta)))~\mathbf{U}(\theta)^\top
\end{align}
How does one compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i} f(\mathbf{A}(\theta))$?

Comment: You mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ I imagine? As I don' see why there should be in index $i$ attached to $\theta$.

Comment: Also $f(A(\theta))$ doesn't make sense as $f$ is a function which domain is $\mathbb R$. Can you fix that?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: I think they're basically overloading the function $f$. They're specifically telling us the definition of $f(A(\theta))$.

Answer (score 1):

For the real function $$F(\theta) \doteq f(A(\theta))$$
the most practical method for calculating the derivative is
the [Complex Step Approximation](https://nhigham.com/2020/10/06/what-is-the-complex-step-approximation/)
$$\eqalign{
\frac{dF}{d\theta} &= {\rm{Im}}\!\left(\frac{F(\theta+i\eta)}{\eta}\right), 
\qquad \eta &\approx 10^{-90} \\
}$$
unless your function has some special structure which can be exploited.

### Update

Invoking the Daleckii-Krein theorem leads to a closed-form expression
$$\eqalign{
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\b{\lambda}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
A &= UL\,U^T \qiq L=\Diag{\b_k} \\
F &= f(A) \\
dF &= U\,\BR{R\odot\LR{U^TdA\:U}\!}\,U^T \\
\\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
R_{jk}
   =  \begin{cases}
  {\Large\frac{f(\b_j)\,-\,f(\b_k)}{\b_j\,-\,\b_k}}\qquad{\rm if}\;\b_j\ne\b_k \\
\\
  \quad{f'(\b_k)}\qquad\qquad{\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases} \\
}$$
where $(\odot)$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and $dA$ can be interpreted as either the *differential* or
as the derivative *with respect* to $\theta_i$